# ArgumentException when loading image from byte array using JpegBitmapDecoder

Tags: c#, .net, image, jpeg

I'm having some trouble reading JPEG files in my class. I need to load metadata and bitmap from a JPEG file. So far, I have this:

```
    public void Load()
    {
        using (Stream imageStream = File.Open(this.FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            BitmapSource source = decoder.Frames[0];

            // load metadata
            this.metadata = source.Metadata as BitmapMetadata;

            // prepare buffer
            int octetsPerPixel = source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
            byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[source.PixelWidth * source.PixelHeight * octetsPerPixel];
            source.CopyPixels(pixelBuffer, source.PixelWidth * octetsPerPixel, 0);

            Stream pixelStream = new MemoryStream(pixelBuffer);

            // load bitmap
            this.bitmap = new Bitmap(pixelStream); // throws ArgumentException
        }

        this.status = PhotoStatus.Loaded;
    }
```

But the Bitmap constructor throws an ArgumentException when trying to create a Bitmap instance from a stream.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx) says:

> **System.ArgumentException**
>
> *stream* does not contain image data or is null.
>
> -or-
>
> *stream* contains a PNG image file with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels.

I'm not sure, what I did wrong. Can you please help me?

Comment: I'm sure you've checked that `FilePath` points to a `Jpeg`? And also that it actually _is_ a `Jpeg`, and not just named as such?

Comment: Well `pixelStream` depends on `pixelBuffer` which depends on some other vars, you need to verify that each one of these has good values, easy to do in the debugger.

Comment: @Chris O: I'm not sure, how I can easily verify the values of pixelBuffer. I don't know the right values, so I can't compare them.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Yes, FilePath points to valid Jpeg file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `Bitmap` constructor which is usually used to load an image file in a known format - JPEG, PNG etc. Instead, you've just got a bunch of bytes, and you're not telling it *anything* about the format you want to use them in.

It's not clear why you want to use BitmapDecoder and BitmapSource at all - why aren't you just using:

```
Stream imageStream = File.Open(this.FilePath, FileMode.Open,
                               FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));
this.bitmap = new Bitmap(imageStream);
```

Note that you *mustn't* use a `using` statement here - the `Bitmap` "owns" the stream after you've called the constructor.

Aside from all of this, you seem to be trying to mix WPF and WinForms ideas of images, which I suspect is a generally bad idea :(

Comment: I'm using it because I need to read BitmapMetadata. Is there some other way to read it? And because I used decoder for metadata, I used it to read bitmap as well.

Comment: @tomp: I suspect the simplest approach is to read the file once to get the metadata, and once more to load the `Bitmap`. Not exactly efficient, but the simplest way of working with the two different types of image library you're dealing with. Do you *definitely* need a Bitmap rather than a BitmapSource in the rest of your code?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I need Bitmap, I'm planning to do image transformations like rotation or cropping on the image. This is my first project on .NET platform and I just haven't learned the best practices yet, but Bitmap seemed to be better solution for this purpose. But how could I work with BitmapSource if I didn't know how to get a Bitmap from it? Also, I still don't know, what exactly is wrong with my code, aside from the mix of WPF and WinForms.

Comment: @tomp: Are you trying to write a WPF/Silverlight or a Windows Forms app? Use the imaging classes in the relevant toolkit - currently you're using a mixture, and that's never going to end well.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: A Windows Forms app. Which tools for Windows Forms can I use to read metadata?

Comment: @tomp: Well, Bitmap has the PropertyItems property... does that give you what you need?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Probably yes. It's not very programmer-friendly (unlike BitmapMetadata), but it serves the purpose.